# Building pcl 1.7.2 from source

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, point-cloud-library

I want to build pcl library version 1.7.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.3, I have cmake version 3.10.2

when I run cmake command I get the following error message:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1947 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.65.1

  Boost include path: /usr/include

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_system
          boost_filesystem
          boost_thread
```

When I write `whereis boost` I get the following result:

```
boost: /usr/include/boost
```

And when I see the content of `/usr/include/boost/version.hpp` it is version 1.65.1.

What confuses me that why this cmake is fails?

I set this option `set(Boost_DEBUG 1)` to see the debug output of find boost and it gives me this result:

```
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1096 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = TRUE
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1098 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1100 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1102 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = 1.47;1.47.0;1.48;1.48.0;1.49;1.49.0
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1104 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1172 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1174 ]   BOOST_ROOT = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1176 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = /usr/include/boost
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1178 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1180 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.47;1.47.0;1.48;1.48.0;1.49;1.49.0;1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1255 ] Include debugging info:
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1257 ]   _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = /usr/include/boost;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//include;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/;PATHS;C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/sw/local/include
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1259 ]   _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = boost-1_47;boost_1_47;boost/boost-1_47;boost/boost_1_47;boost-1_47_0;boost_1_47_0;boost/boost-1_47_0;boost/boost_1_47_0;boost-1_48;boost_1_48;boost/boost-1_48;boost/boost_1_48;boost-1_48_0;boost_1_48_0;boost/boost-1_48_0;boost/boost_1_48_0;boost-1_49;boost_1_49;boost/boost-1_49;boost/boost_1_49;boost-1_49_0;boost_1_49_0;boost/boost-1_49_0;boost/boost_1_49_0;boost-1_65_1;boost_1_65_1;boost/boost-1_65_1;boost/boost_1_65_1;boost-1_65_0;boost_1_65_0;boost/boost-1_65_0;boost/boost_1_65_0;boost-1_65;boost_1_65;boost/boost-1_65;boost/boost_1_65;boost-1_64_0;boost_1_64_0;boost/boost-1_64_0;boost/boost_1_64_0;boost-1_64;boost_1_64;boost/boost-1_64;boost/boost_1_64;boost-1_63_0;boost_1_63_0;boost/boost-1_63_0;boost/boost_1_63_0;boost-1_63;boost_1_63;boost/boost-1_63;boost/boost_1_63;boost-1_62_0;boost_1_62_0;boost/boost-1_62_0;boost/boost_1_62_0;boost-1_62;boost_1_62;boost/boost-1_62;boost/boost_1_62;boost-1_61_0;boost_1_61_0;boost/boost-1_61_0;boost/boost_1_61_0;boost-1_61;boost_1_61;boost/boost-1_61;boost/boost_1_61;boost-1_60_0;boost_1_60_0;boost/boost-1_60_0;boost/boost_1_60_0;boost-1_60;boost_1_60;boost/boost-1_60;boost/boost_1_60;boost-1_59_0;boost_1_59_0;boost/boost-1_59_0;boost/boost_1_59_0;boost-1_59;boost_1_59;boost/boost-1_59;boost/boost_1_59;boost-1_58_0;boost_1_58_0;boost/boost-1_58_0;boost/boost_1_58_0;boost-1_58;boost_1_58;boost/boost-1_58;boost/boost_1_58;boost-1_57_0;boost_1_57_0;boost/boost-1_57_0;boost/boost_1_57_0;boost-1_57;boost_1_57;boost/boost-1_57;boost/boost_1_57;boost-1_56_0;boost_1_56_0;boost/boost-1_56_0;boost/boost_1_56_0;boost-1_56;boost_1_56;boost/boost-1_56;boost/boost_1_56;boost-1_55_0;boost_1_55_0;boost/boost-1_55_0;boost/boost_1_55_0;boost-1_55;boost_1_55;boost/boost-1_55;boost/boost_1_55;boost-1_54_0;boost_1_54_0;boost/boost-1_54_0;boost/boost_1_54_0;boost-1_54;boost_1_54;boost/boost-1_54;boost/boost_1_54;boost-1_53_0;boost_1_53_0;boost/boost-1_53_0;boost/boost_1_53_0;boost-1_53;boost_1_53;boost/boost-1_53;boost/boost_1_53;boost-1_52_0;boost_1_52_0;boost/boost-1_52_0;boost/boost_1_52_0;boost-1_52;boost_1_52;boost/boost-1_52;boost/boost_1_52;boost-1_51_0;boost_1_51_0;boost/boost-1_51_0;boost/boost_1_51_0;boost-1_51;boost_1_51;boost/boost-1_51;boost/boost_1_51;boost-1_50_0;boost_1_50_0;boost/boost-1_50_0;boost/boost_1_50_0;boost-1_50;boost_1_50;boost/boost-1_50;boost/boost_1_50;boost-1_49_0;boost_1_49_0;boost/boost-1_49_0;boost/boost_1_49_0;boost-1_49;boost_1_49;boost/boost-1_49;boost/boost_1_49;boost-1_48_0;boost_1_48_0;boost/boost-1_48_0;boost/boost_1_48_0;boost-1_48;boost_1_48;boost/boost-1_48;boost/boost_1_48;boost-1_47_0;boost_1_47_0;boost/boost-1_47_0;boost/boost_1_47_0;boost-1_47;boost_1_47;boost/boost-1_47;boost/boost_1_47
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1279 ] location of version.hpp: /usr/include/boost/version.hpp
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1303 ] version.hpp reveals boost 1.65.1
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1389 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = -gcc48
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1399 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1443 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1445 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -d
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1507 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//lib;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//stage/lib;/usr/include/lib;/usr/include/../lib;/usr/include/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG   = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//lib;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//stage/lib;/usr/include/lib;/usr/include/../lib;/usr/include/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1657 ] Searching for SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_serialization-gcc48-mt-1_65_1;boost_serialization-gcc48-mt;boost_serialization-mt-1_65_1;boost_serialization-mt;boost_serialization
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1708 ] Searching for SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_serialization-gcc48-mt-d-1_65_1;boost_serialization-gcc48-mt-d;boost_serialization-mt-d-1_65_1;boost_serialization-mt-d;boost_serialization-mt;boost_serialization
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1657 ] Searching for MPI_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_mpi-gcc48-mt-1_65_1;boost_mpi-gcc48-mt;boost_mpi-mt-1_65_1;boost_mpi-mt;boost_mpi
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1708 ] Searching for MPI_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_mpi-gcc48-mt-d-1_65_1;boost_mpi-gcc48-mt-d;boost_mpi-mt-d-1_65_1;boost_mpi-mt-d;boost_mpi-mt;boost_mpi
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1783 ] Boost_FOUND = 1
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1094 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.47;1.47.0;1.48;1.48.0;1.49;1.49.0;1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1096 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = TRUE
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1098 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1100 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1102 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = 1.47;1.47.0;1.48;1.48.0;1.49;1.49.0
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1104 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1172 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1174 ]   BOOST_ROOT = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1176 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = /usr/include/boost
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1178 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1180 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.47;1.47.0;1.48;1.48.0;1.49;1.49.0;1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1279 ] location of version.hpp: /usr/include/boost/version.hpp
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1303 ] version.hpp reveals boost 1.65.1
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1389 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = -gcc48
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1399 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1443 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1445 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -d
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1507 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG   = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1657 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_system-gcc48-mt-1_65_1;boost_system-gcc48-mt;boost_system-mt-1_65_1;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1708 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_system-gcc48-mt-d-1_65_1;boost_system-gcc48-mt-d;boost_system-mt-d-1_65_1;boost_system-mt-d;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1657 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_filesystem-gcc48-mt-1_65_1;boost_filesystem-gcc48-mt;boost_filesystem-mt-1_65_1;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1708 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_filesystem-gcc48-mt-d-1_65_1;boost_filesystem-gcc48-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt-d-1_65_1;boost_filesystem-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1657 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_thread-gcc48-mt-1_65_1;boost_thread-gcc48-mt;boost_thread-mt-1_65_1;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1708 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_thread-gcc48-mt-d-1_65_1;boost_thread-gcc48-mt-d;boost_thread-mt-d-1_65_1;boost_thread-mt-d;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1657 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_date_time-gcc48-mt-1_65_1;boost_date_time-gcc48-mt;boost_date_time-mt-1_65_1;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1708 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_date_time-gcc48-mt-d-1_65_1;boost_date_time-gcc48-mt-d;boost_date_time-mt-d-1_65_1;boost_date_time-mt-d;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1657 ] Searching for IOSTREAMS_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_iostreams-gcc48-mt-1_65_1;boost_iostreams-gcc48-mt;boost_iostreams-mt-1_65_1;boost_iostreams-mt;boost_iostreams
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1708 ] Searching for IOSTREAMS_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_iostreams-gcc48-mt-d-1_65_1;boost_iostreams-gcc48-mt-d;boost_iostreams-mt-d-1_65_1;boost_iostreams-mt-d;boost_iostreams-mt;boost_iostreams
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1657 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_chrono-gcc48-mt-1_65_1;boost_chrono-gcc48-mt;boost_chrono-mt-1_65_1;boost_chrono-mt;boost_chrono
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1708 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_chrono-gcc48-mt-d-1_65_1;boost_chrono-gcc48-mt-d;boost_chrono-mt-d-1_65_1;boost_chrono-mt-d;boost_chrono-mt;boost_chrono
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1657 ] Searching for ATOMIC_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_atomic-gcc48-mt-1_65_1;boost_atomic-gcc48-mt;boost_atomic-mt-1_65_1;boost_atomic-mt;boost_atomic
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1708 ] Searching for ATOMIC_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_atomic-gcc48-mt-d-1_65_1;boost_atomic-gcc48-mt-d;boost_atomic-mt-d-1_65_1;boost_atomic-mt-d;boost_atomic-mt;boost_atomic
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1657 ] Searching for REGEX_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_regex-gcc48-mt-1_65_1;boost_regex-gcc48-mt;boost_regex-mt-1_65_1;boost_regex-mt;boost_regex
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1708 ] Searching for REGEX_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_regex-gcc48-mt-d-1_65_1;boost_regex-gcc48-mt-d;boost_regex-mt-d-1_65_1;boost_regex-mt-d;boost_regex-mt;boost_regex
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1783 ] Boost_FOUND = 1
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1947 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.65.1

  Boost include path: /usr/include

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_system
          boost_filesystem
          boost_thread

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
```

similar solutions on the web suggest to set `BOOST_ROOT` and `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` and `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` explicitly, But I don't know what values I should set for them, I tried these two line of codes in my cmake file but still got the same error (also I deleted the build folder ...)

```
SET(BOOST_ROOT "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/")
SET(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "/usr/include/boost")
```

Any help is much appreciated, It has been days since I have this problem and this is my first exposure to building C++ solution.

**Edit:** When I write this command: `ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost*.so` it does not show `boost_system` `boost_filesystem` and `boost_thread` ! Although I installed boost whit this command: `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`

Comment: Please understand C and C++ are 2 different languages - Just because C is an *almost* subset of C++ doesn't make them the same. Do not tag a C++ problem with C. It makes things difficult for others.

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer I agree with what you say, But for my question both a C++ programmer and a C programmer can answer, Although I found myself what the problem was.

Comment: I just wanted to delete this question because of down votes it got but stackoverflow said: "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center.". When others won't appreciated my effort ... When the Gods of stackoverflow are not happy with this noob question ...

Comment: It's OK. I don't claim to know why the down-votes. But if it makes you feel better, I didn't down vote this question. Besides, if someone down votes it, they will incur -5 to their reputation. That said, the question is about missing/poorly installed SDK that isn't worded properly. Even your answer doesn't explain how reinstalling fixed. Perhaps read through some good Q&A and see how you could improve it. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to solve it by completely removing boost and installing it again.

Comment: You were missing some boost libraries earlier (as noted by CMake), and you probably installed libboost-all-dev or it's equivalent the second time around. There was no need to remove boost.